# Delete RandomAccessFile from directory

Tags: java

I have a random access file that holds some information generated at run time that needs to be deleted from the directory when the program terminates. From what I have found, random access files don't have a delete method like regular files and all that I have found is:

```
RandomAccessFile temp = new RandomAccessFile ("temp.tmp", "rw");
temp = new File(NetSimView.filename);
temp.delete();
```

This obviously doesn't work, and I haven't been able to find anything on NetSimView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`RandomAccessFile` does not have a delete method.
Creating a new `File` object for the file to be deleted is fine. However, before doing that, you need to insure the `RandomAccessFile` that references the same file is closed by calling `RandomAccessFile.close()`

If you want to have the file deleted when the program terminates, you can do something like:

```
File file = new File("somefile.txt");

//Use the try-with-resources to create the RandomAccessFile
//Which takes care of closing the file once leaving the try block
try(RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")){

    //do some writing to the file...
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

file.deleteOnExit(); //Will delete the file just before the program exits
```

Notice the comments above the `try` statement, using a try-with-resources and also notice the last line of code where we call `file.deleteOnExit()` to delete the file upon program termination.

Comment: Thanks, I was fixated on deleting the file with my RandomAccessFile object that I didn't think to just create a regular file object to do my deleting.